# Java's Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)) produces unsigned bytes

Tags: java

So the problem I have is, that I want to read any file as a byte array and then do something with it. However the "do-something-with-it" does not work because the methods throw an exception if the bytes that are used are out of the range of a signed byte, which is exactly what `Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path))` produces. The first byte of the file I test on is `11101111 (=-17)` for example. Strangely however, this problem does not arise with text files.

So my question is, why does `Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path))` produce unsigned bytes if they allegedly don't even exist in java (or are not supported) and how can I circumvent that?

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Java does not support signed bytes, at least directly. I'm not sure what your question is: does your method expect signed bytes? Or just that the bytes have values less than 128?

Comment: @BobDalgleish: Java doesn't support **unsigned** bytes.

Comment: A byte is a byte. It contains 8 bits. By default, one bit is considered as a sign bit, and the byte is displayed as a signed number. But you may choose to convert it as an unsigned int (or short) if you want to, and display it as an unsigned number. You'll have to provide the code you're using and tell us what you expect it to do and what it does instead if you want help. As is, the question doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have been cheated by [java.lang.Byte.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#toString%28%29) which by default print signed representation of bytes.

> Returns a String object representing this Byte's value. **The value is converted to signed decimal representation** and returned as a string, exactly as if the byte value were given as an argument to the toString(byte) method.

But the byte is still signed :) **This is your job to handle it as signed value.**

For example:

```
byte sample = (byte) -1;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(sample & 0xFF))
```

will print:

```
11111111
```